# OpenVPN subnet routing on openSuSE

Tags: routing, openvpn, subnet, opensuse

First off: I have looked all over for a solution to this, but couldn't find anything.

How can I make OpenVPN's subnet accessible to my LAN?

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION:**

I have an openSUSE 12.1 box that is my NAT router. The internet is on eth0 and my LAN (10.0.0.0/24) is on eth1. OpenVPN creates the tun0 device, which I also added manually to the network interfaces list in YaST, so to be able to assign it to the firewall's internal zone.
OpenVPN's subnet is 10.0.1.0/24.

I have checked "Enable IP Forwarding" in YaST's "Network Settings" and I am using "Masquerade Networks in YaST's SuSEFirewall settings.
In `/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2` I have set `FW_MASQ_NETS="10.0.0.0/25 10.0.1.0/24"`
The "Network Settings"' routing table is currently empty.

At this point I can reach 10.0.0.0/24 and the rest of the world from my VPN's 10.0.1.0/24, since OpenVPN's `server.conf` sais `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`.

**QUESTION:**

What I want now is to be able to reach VPN-connected machines (10.0.1.0/24) from my LAN (10.0.0.0/24). How do I do this the right way in *openSuSE*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you should already be able to do that (unless you have some firewall rules in place that disallow this).

Since your vpn server acts as a default gateway for both your networks (vpn+internal), and it knows the all the correct routes, it should work without any additional settings. Both networks are "locally connected" (OpenVPN acts as a local interface too, so it's route is immediately added), so no need for additional routes.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, but in practice it seems like packtes from a 10.0.0.0/24 address never find their way to a 10.0.1.0/24 address. The funny thing is though, that a ping from the VPN subnet to the LAN subnet _does_ yield a return packet.